# "Replace YouTube Link with iframe Youtube video Player" Using ASP.NET+C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I run a forum and I want to automatically replace any link to a YouTube video with a iframe youtube video player using ASP.NET+C#.

How to replace this Link

http://youtu.be/uN-A8eHte1g

with

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" frameborder="0" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/uN-A8eHte1g?rel=0&amp;wmode=Opaque" title="YouTube video player" type="text/html" width="100%"></iframe>
```

I can't really find anything like this on the ineternet.

Hope someone could help me this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This terribly needs more information. Do you have access to modify the code of the forum? Can you post the code where you are rendering the youtube video link? Or can you modify the javascript of the page (I noticed you have tagged as Javascript)

Comment: @DarylTeo Sorry for the inconvenience. I've already edited my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand this code is in php and you want a c# example but this will give information regarding the approach you should take. Also the php code is very easy to read and should be fairly simple to concvert into c#.

http://mattcrouch.net/blog/2011/01/converting-urls-into-links-and-youtube-videos/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways:

You can modify links at server side with C# code, when saving user messages.

You can do this using SQL trigger on Insert and Update table, that contains user messages.

You can change links at client side by Java Script. Just select all messages on page using JQuery selectors and replace links.

To find links in string use regexp